# WPF - Databind dynamic control type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, controls

I have a Person class. A Person can have an associated control. Can I display the control through data binding?

e.g: Name: Bill , Control: TextBox
     Name: Bob, Control: ComboBox
     Name: Dan, Control: CheckBox

I have the following xaml in my resource dictionary

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name: " DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
       </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to add the associated user control to the dockpanel, Can this be done

Something like??

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name: " DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Control Type = "{Binding Control}"/>
       </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, at least initially:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}"/>
```

NB: if your UI binds to this property in more than one place, you could get an exception due to the attempt to parent the control in multiple places.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work but am coming up short. I would expect the below to show a textbox: 
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TextBox ControlType = new TextBox(){Text = "test"};
     }
.
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name: " DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" />
             <ContentControl Content="{Binding ControlType}"/>
       </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

Comment: @Dan, in your sample class, I would try making ControlType a 'full-on' C# property rather than a public field.

Comment: Also, ProTip: take a look in the Output window of Visual Studio for any binding error messages.

Comment: Thank you. Encapsulating the field worked, would never have guessed that. I assumed a public field had the same visibility as a public property. Now, that I am thinking about it, I guess it does make sense, behind the scenes it is probably <guessing here> doing somthing like invoke(methodName), if its a field this will fail.  Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of any theoretical problem with binding to public fields, but WPF data binding just doesnt support it. I have been hit by that before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a ContentControl in this case:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}" />
```

That'll just render whatever you give it. If the Person's "Control" property is a WPF control, it'll render that.